# Displaying Chinese Characters in Apache/Tomcat server

Tags: java, apache, jsp, utf-8

I'm trying to modify my web application so that it can be used in multiple languages but am having some difficulty and still experiencing issues.  I'm developing in Eclipse using the Apache Struts framework (Java servlets and jsp pages).  At the moment if I try to create a jsp page and have it display chinese characters, the chinese characters will display correctly in the broser.  However, if I call a function from a Java class, it will display only '??' in the browser.  I suspect the compiler is the problem, but and am wondering if anyone has experienced something similar and was able to fix it.

Here is what I have done so far: 
When I began working on this project everything was encoded in ISO-8859-1.
I modified my IDE (eclipse) so that all of the source files are saved in UTF-8. 
I then modified our database (Firebird) so that the data that I am displaying is UTF-8. 
I modified the jsp files so the charset is set in the head 
Modified the web.xml files to specify utf-8 as their encoding

If I create a simple jsp page and try to display chinese characters it will display correctly in the browser:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
         <%="密碼" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, if I call a function from a Java class, it will display simply '??' instead of the chinese characters:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <%=com.enrolnet.shared.multilanguage.MultiLanguageTest.mtest() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

MultiLanguageTest:

```
public class MultiLanguageTest {
    public static String mtest() {
        return "密碼";
    }
}
```

Anyone have any insight on what might be going on here and how I can fix it?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

You should set the encoding of the page to utf-8, not just in a meta tag.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Taken from the [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/WebI18N5.html).